# Toilet water leak - water tank types

Tags: water, leak, toilet

I'm just experiencing an issue with water tank in our 20-30 old years old house (Czech rep. for location reference). I have studied type of expansions on Internet for (few hours) + visited shop with toilets and I was unable to find same model/type of `output ventil` (unsure about name) from the tank.

Photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGPeV.jpg

There is pipe coming from the bottom hole, whene You pull the string, it will take the top of tube and put it under the water surface/level.

How I imagine it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv0Wy.jpg

The leak itself goes from water tank to the toilet (through its normal path).

**Questions:** Have You seen anyone this system somewhere? Where the leak might come from? Could You provide "name" or "brand" for this type of tank to find spare parts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In 1969-70 in Fiji I used a toilet with the tank about 6 or 7 ft above the toilet. It was operated with a pull chain which one had to pull quickly to initiate a flush; a slow pull would not initiate a flush. I never got up on a ladder or asked anyone how these worked, but I assumed the pull somehow started a siphon. The advantage of this would be that no flapper valve would be needed. A worn or improperly installed flapper valve is a source of leaks. If I recall correctly the down tube (~1.5" to 2" diameter) to the toilet bowl came out of the bottom of the tank rather than over the side.

Comment: Siphon (or syphon) valves are not used in the US (or at least are not common), but seem to be widely used in the UK. The modern ones in the UK are compact and made of plastic but still work via a syphon as opposed to a simple drain out the bottom closed by a flapper valve. From your picture I would guess yours is a syphon and not a new one. If that is the case (since a syphon cannot leak), then I would say it is leaking through a broken or corroded overflow tube. The overflow tube probably connects to the flush tube.